# Pillow package is required but i already have the latest version

Tags: python, web-scraping, visual-studio-code, pyautogui

So I'm trying to use `pyautogui` for a web scraper but I get this exception:

> "The Pillow package is required to use this function"

I already have the latest version of Pillow

Here's the code:

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.sleep(3)

pyautogui.press('win')
pyautogui.typewrite('google')
pyautogui.press('enter')
pyautogui.sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite('youtube.com')
pyautogui.press('enter')

coords = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('new_tab.png')
pyautogui.click(coords)
```

Here's the line generating the error:

```py
coords = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('new_tab.png')
```

NOTE: I am using:
Windows 10
Python 3.9.0
VSCode

Comment: -Please install the dependency package "pillow" in the currently selected VSCode environment.(_pip install pillow_). In addition, you could use "_pip show pillow_" in the terminal to check whether the module is installed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually figured it out! Basically, I had to move the PIL package to site-packages,  restart VSCode, and `import PIL` and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can import Pillow at the start of your code:

```
import PIL
```

Comment: "No module named 'PIL'" is the exception I get when I do that but when i ctrl+click it it takes me to a __init__.py file

Comment: So I changed the location of the PIL Package to site-packages and i dont get the "No module named PIL" exception anymore but I still get the original one ("The Pillow package is required to use this function")